# Synchronize two processes using two different states

Tags: c, linux, shared-memory

I am trying to work out a way to synchronize two processes which share data.

Basically I have two processes linked using shared memory.  I need process A to set some data in the shared memory area, then process B to read that data and act on it.

The sequence of events I am looking to have is:

1. B blocks waiting for data available signal
2. A writes data
3. A signals data available
4. B reads data
5. B blocks waiting for data not available signal
6. A signals data not available
7. All goes back to the beginning.

In other terms, B would block until it got a "1" signal, get the data, then block again until that signal went to "0".

I have managed to emulate it OK using purely shared memory, but either I block using a while loop which consumes 100% of CPU time, or I use a while loop with a nanosleep in it which sometimes misses some of the signals.

I have tried using semaphores, but I can only find a way to wait for a zero, not for a one, and trying to use two semaphores just didn't work.  I don't think semaphores are the way to go.

There will be numerous processes all accessing the same shared memory area, and all processes need to be notified when that shared memory has been modified.

It's basically trying to emulate a hardware data and control bus, where events are edge rather than level triggered.  It's the transitions between states I am interested in, rather than the states themselves.

So, any ideas or thoughts?

Comment: How does a loop consume 100% of memory?

Comment: PS: you might look at using pthreads data structs, in this case condition variables. (yes, I know you're using seperate processes, but you can throw the condvar in the shared memory segment)

Comment: oops.. that should have been 100% of cpu time.

Comment: @H2CO3 Signals would be nice, but I cannot predict what processes will be accessing the shared memory.  It could be many processes.

Comment: Shared memory sounds like the source of your problems. Why not use a more appropriate IPC mechanism?

Comment: What other IPC mechanism will give the ability to have an instantaneous value shared amongst multiple processes?  I cannot "broadcast" the value to multiple processes.  Queues also don't give an instantaneous value.

Answer (score 2):

Linux has its own [**`eventfd(2)`**](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/eventfd.2.html) facility that you can incorporate into your normal `poll`/`select` loop. You can pass `eventfd` file descriptor from process to process through a UNIX socket the usual way, or just inherit it with `fork(2)`.

#### Edit 0:

After re-reading the question I think one of your options is signals and process groups: start your "listening" processes under the same process group ([`setpgid(2)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/setpgid.2.html)), then signal them all with negative `pid` argument to [`kill(2)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/kill.2.html) or [`sigqueue(2)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/sigqueue.2.html). Again, Linux provides [`signalfd(2)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/signalfd.2.html) for polling and avoiding slow signal trampolines.

Comment: How well would that work with say 15 processes, any one of which could be needing to indicate to the other 14 that the shared memory value has changed?

Comment: I would go with something like local multicast for one-to-many announcements like this. Pipes are good for one-to-one. Sorry missed the part of your question about the "many".

Answer (score 0):

If 2 processes are involved you can use a file , shared memory or even networking to pass the flag or signal. But if the processes are more, there may be some suitable solutions in modifying the kernel. There is one shared memory in your question, right ?! How the signals are passed now ?!

Comment: The best I have managed to do is to have a second byte of shared memory with flags in it, acting as "control" lines.  The processes wait for changes in this byte by repeated polling in a while() loop.  That is too processor intensive though.  Adding a delay, even with nanosleep, means that some of the changes get missed.  I still need this extra byte to control other things, but need some way of notifying when it changes.  It could change many thousands of times a second, and multiple processes need to know that.

Comment: Process A puts a signal in your second shared memory in order to inform Process B about new data. Can process A change this second shared memory and its flags when the B hasn't read them all ?! As you say Process A can change it and exactly now, B is in nano sleep, right ?

Comment: yes, A can change the data at any time, whether B has read it or not.  In effect, process A is like a CPU, just setting values on Address and Data busses.  Process B is like a RAM chip, waiting for certain combinations on certain busses before reacting to them.  Process A cannot wait for confirmation from B because B may not be supposed to respond to the current data.  It may be C that responds, or Q, or none of them at all.  I cannot predict what will or won't be responsible for handling the data in the shared memory.

Comment: When I encounter such patterns, a queue passes through my mind. I know here the problem is different, but If process A can wait for a signal from B for reading the flags in order to make A get sure about flags are delivered, it seems the problem is solved but if the number of processes go higher this will be a bad solution. As well you say process A doesn't wait for anything. Another scenario can be seen as this, process A puts the flags in a queue and process B reads the queue.his is not suitable for this problem because A will change data whenever the new flags are put in the second ...

Comment: the second shared memory. Can we have a queue which data goes in it ?! And all the processes or in this special case, process B removes from this queue. I mean is there any structure to do this for you ?! If you you use networking e.g TCP connections, an internal queue is made. If you want to write it in Kernel space you can have a queue there.

Comment: Queues are not suitable for this application, unfortunately.  They did cross my mind, but the shared memory has to contain an instantaneous value that is guaranteed to be the same for all processes reading it.  With queues each process may be getting different values as they may be reading the queue at different speeds.

Comment: So each process can have its own queue. OK, let's forget the queues. You can also make a character device. Process B is a driver or has a driver which reads this read only device. Process A can receive the data in kernel space and write them to the device. Have you thought about this ?! Now a file is shared between Process A and B. If there are more processes, process B can send a copy to each of those processes. This problem has a certain complexity. All we are doing, we are balancing the complexity. It is obvious that all of these work rounds can have a bad effect on the speed.

Comment: I can't do anything kernel level.  (Well, I can, but the processes can't.)  It has to all be user-land.

Comment: Can we use a SIGNAL like TERM to Process B to make it aware to read the data !? I mean we can send kill signal to a specific process, but Process B can manage this signal in order to get aware about new data in the shared memory. A bad side effect is, when the OS sending the kill command , the process won't close normally.

Comment: Process A would have to know of the existence (and PID) of process B. Also, if there are 15 processes, that's a lot of signals being sent out by process A, which adds extra latency I'd rather avoid.  I'd prefer a mechanism that a process can subscribe to and use to send a signal to all the other subscribed process.

Answer (score 0):

In linux, all POSIX control structures (mutex, conditions, read-write-locks, semaphores) have an option such that they also can be used between processes if they reside in shared memory. For the process that you describe a classic mutex/condition pair seem to fit the job well. Look into the man pages of the `..._init` functions for these structures.

Linux has other proper utilities such as "futex" to handle this even more efficiently. But these are probably not the right tools to start with.

Answer (score 0):

1 Single Reader & Single Writer
**1 Single Reader & Single Writer**
    This can be implemented using semaphores.
In posix semaphore api, you have sem_wait() which will wait until value of the semaphore count is zero once it is incremented using sem_post from other process the wait will finish.

In this case you have to use 2 semaphores for synchronization.

**process 1 (reader)**
sem_wait(sem1);
.......
sem_post(sem2);

**process 2(writer)**
sem_wait(sem2);
.......
sem_post(sem1);

In this way you can achieve synchronization in shared memory.